# Avoid box-shadow of sibling elements overlap one another

Tags: css, box-shadow

I'm trying to have few shapes inside a common parent and apply shadow to them. When I do so, The shadow of proceeding siblings overlap the previous ones. I went through z-index's but couldn't seem to work it out. Can someone explain whats happening here and what can be done to achieve what I want.

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #333;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .shape-wrapper {
      opacity: 0.99;
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .shape-wrapper .shape-inner {
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
        transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .shape-wrapper .shape-inner:nth-child(2) {
      left: 50%;
    }
    .shape-wrapper .shape-inner:nth-child(3) {
      top: 50%;
    }
    .shape-wrapper .shape-inner:nth-child(4) {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    .shape-wrapper .shape-inner .shape {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #000;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      box-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="shape-wrapper">
        <div class="shape-inner">
            <div class="shape shape-1">Shape1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="shape-inner">
            <div class="shape shape-2">Shape2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="shape-inner">
            <div class="shape shape-3">Shape3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="shape-inner">
            <div class="shape shape-4">Shape4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/husainitis/1amh7tou/) for my fiddle.

[How It Is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nSEY.jpg)

[How I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg7BA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put the box-shadow on the pseudoelements (::before) of the boxes and then apply z-index -1 on the ::before elements.

It has its drawbacks though. Mainly that the parent of the pseudoelements has to have overflow visible.

```
.shape-wrapper {
   .shape-inner {
      overflow:visible;
   }
   .shape-inner::before {
       content: '';
       box-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
       z-index: -1;
       position: absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       right:0;
       bottom:0;
   }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oqgrb1eu/2/

Answer (score -1):

Try to make `position: relative` of all boxes and `z-index` equal on all boxes.